# Triggering a function after ajax call has finished loading images in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.1

I've got an image gallery on my page, which works a lot like pinterest.

```
$images = Images::paginate(5);
```

On my image page, I start off with 5 images.

**Controller:**

```
if($request->ajax()) {
    return [
        'images' => view('browse.partials.imagePartials')->with(compact('images'))->render(), 'next_page' => $images->nextPageUrl()
    ];
}           

return view('browse.combined_results')->with('images', $images);
```

**Markup:**

```
<div id="freewall" class="freewall endless-pagination" data-next-page={{ $images->nextPageUrl() }}>
@foreach ($images as $image)
<a href="{{ route('image.get', ['username' => $image->created_by_username, 'URLtitle' => $image->url_title]) }}">
    <div class='brick featuredTextContainer' style="width:150px">
        <img src='{{ url($image->medium_path) }}' width='100%' class="profileImg">
        <span class="featuredArtistName">{{ $image->title }}</span>             
    </div>
</a>
@endforeach
</div>
```

These images are arranged using freewall:

```
var wall = new Freewall("#freewall");
wall.reset({
    selector: '.brick',
    animate: true,
    cellW: 150,
    cellH: 'auto',
    onResize: function() {
        wall.fitWidth();
    }
});

var images = wall.container.find('.brick');
images.find('img').on('load', function() {
    wall.fitWidth();
});

wall.fitWidth();
```

wall.fitWidth() is the method that arranges the images all neatly, like so:

[image]

However, if you scroll down, you get an ajax request

```
$(window).scroll(fetchImages);

function fetchImages() {
    var page = $('.endless-pagination').data('next-page');

    if(page !== null) {

        clearTimeout( $.data( this, "scrollCheck" ) );

        $.data( this, "scrollCheck", setTimeout(function() {
            var scroll_position_for_images_load = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() + 100;

            if(scroll_position_for_images_load >= $(document).height()) {
                $.get(page, function(data){
                    $('.endless-pagination').append(data.images);
                    $('.endless-pagination').data('next-page', data.next_page);
                });

            }
        }, 350))

    }
}
```

The ajax request loads a partial, which is essentially just the next page of the pagination.

**imagePartial.blade.php**

```
@foreach ($images as $image)
        <a href="{{ route('image.get', ['username' => $image->created_by_username, 'URLtitle' => $image->url_title]) }}">
            <div class='brick featuredTextContainer' style="width:150px">
                <img src='{{ url($image->medium_path) }}' width='100%' class="profileImg">
                <span class="featuredArtistName">{{ $image->title }}</span>             
            </div>
        </a>
@endforeach
```

In other words, it loads in more images from the $images pagination into the images container.

Which is great. It works. However, the images aren't arranged right away. You have to execute `wall.fitWidth()` once more for the images to fit into place. The problem is, I can't simply put this at the end of the `fetchImages` function, because the images take a moment to load in. Therefore, all the images are loaded behind the other images, unarranged.

A solution to this would be to, say, have the new images loaded in with opacity set to 0, have the `wall.fitWidth()` function executed *after* a check to make sure all the images have been loaded into the DOM, THEN set the images back to opacity: 1. But I'm not sure how to do this.

Help?

Comment: need to do same thing as on page load but do it inside the `$.get` callback, right after you append the new ones

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this - prepare one variable

```
var loading = 0;
```

and a function

```
function imageLoaded(){
 loading -= 1;
 if(loadingImages == 0){
  wall.fitWidth();
  var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
  for(var i=0;i<imgs.length;i++)
   if(imgs[i].style.opacity == '0')
    imgs[i].style.opacity = '1';
 }
}
```

then add this to all the image elements / to the image template

```
onload="imageLoaded();" style="opacity:0;"
```

and finally whenever you load new images, increase the *loading* variable by the amount of new images.

**Edit:**

In reply to your comment :

```
onload="loading-=1;if(loadingImages==0){wall.fitWidth();var imgs=document.getElementsByTagName('img');for(var i=0;i<imgs.length;i++)if(imgs[i].style.opacity=='0')imgs[i].style.opacity='1';}}" style="opacity:0;"
```

It's ugly, but makes sure there won't be any context errors.

Comment: I get what you're trying to do, but I get the error ReferenceError: imageLoaded is not defined. Is this because the onload is in a partial being loaded in? I tried moving the js from the bottom to the top of the page and I still get this error.

Comment: Could be, I am not sure. Try changing it to window.imageLoaded = function(){...} or alternatively put the whole imageLoaded function in the onload="" property. I will edit the answer to show what I mean.

Comment: ok, but the problem still resides. The wall.fitWidth() method isn't being recognized in the partial.